# If multiple Blots with the same tagName are created, partial decoration deletion is not possible

Tags: quill

Underlining and FontFamily each created its own Blot.

```
class CustomUnderlineBlot extends Inline {
    static blotName = 'custom-underline';
    static tagName = 'span';

    static create() {
        let node = super.create();
        node.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
        node.setAttribute('data-custom-underline', true);  // 追加の属性
        return node;
    }

    static formats(node) {
        if (node.getAttribute('data-custom-underline')) {  // 独自の属性で判定
            return node.style.textDecoration === 'underline';
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class CustomFontFamilyBlot extends Inline {
    static blotName = 'custom-font-family';
    static tagName = 'span';
    static create(value) {
        let node = super.create();
        node.style.fontFamily = value;
        node.setAttribute('data-custom-font-family', true);
        return node;
    }

    static formats(node) {
        if (node.getAttribute('data-custom-font-family')) {
            return node.style.fontFamily;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Quill.register({
    'formats/custom-underline': CustomUnderlineBlot,
    'formats/custom-font-family': CustomFontFamilyBlot,
});
```

The process when the button is pressed is as follows.

```
const toggleUnderline = () => {
    const range = editor.getSelection();
    if (range) {
        const format = editor.getFormat(range.index, range.length);
        if (format['custom-underline']) {
            editor.formatText(range.index, range.length, 'custom-underline', false);
        } else {
            editor.formatText(range.index, range.length, 'custom-underline', true);
        }
    }
};
```

Now all I want is a text change that will result in the following output.

```
<!--      Decorate the whole once      -->
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline">text</span></p>

<!--      Ideal system if only 'ex' is undecorated      -->
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline">t</span>ex<span style="text-decoration: underline">t</span></p>

<!--      But it comes down to this.      -->
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline">t</span>ext</p>
```

This phenomenon does not occur if the registration order is changed as shown below.
However, the same phenomenon occurs on the font family side.

```
Quill.register({
    'formats/custom-font-family': CustomFontFamilyBlot,
    'formats/custom-underline': CustomUnderlineBlot,
});
```

I am having trouble identifying the cause.

The same tagName (span) cannot be removed. We really want to use the same tagName.

Can you help me?